# How get values that return sp.site.createModernTeamSite in pnpjs

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnpjs

Using below function:

```
const s = await sp.site.createModernTeamSite(
    CustomerName,
    CustomerID,
    true,
    1033,
    "Customer Site for " + CustomerName);
```

You can create a team Site, but how to get values from `s`?

In the console, I can see `GroupId` value. But from code, I am not able access to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createModernTeamSite returns `Promise<void>` so you need get the value from callback function.

```
createModernTeamSite(displayName: string, alias: string, isPublic?: boolean, lcid?: number, description?: string, classification?: string, owners?: string[], hubSiteId?: string, siteDesignId?: string): Promise<void>;

sp.site.createModernTeamSite(
"LeeSPFxModernTeamA",
"LeeSPFxModernTeamA",
true,
1033,
"description")
.then((d:any) => {
    if(d.d){
      var groupId=d.d.CreateGroupEx.GroupId;
    }else{
      console.log(d);
    }
})
```

Comment: Excelent, thanks so much!!! I try in this way and I can get the values.

Answer (score 0):

The `createModernTeamSite` function is `async` which returns `Promise<void>`. So, you need to `await` while it returns some value.

You can use your code like below:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";

sp.site.createModernTeamSite(
    CustomerName,
    CustomerID,
    true,
    1033,
    "Customer Site for " + CustomerName)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

When you will expand `data` in console, you will see all the information returned by `createModernTeamSite()`.

You can follow below documentation to see the properties you can pass to `createModernTeamSite()`.

**official documentation**: [Create a modern team site](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/sites/#create-a-modern-team-site).